# How to mock https 'on' function in jest?

Tags: https, mocking, jestjs

Of course I don't want to call any real endpoints in my test. But I can't figure out how to mock the `.on()` function of `https.get()`.

I'm not exactly sure what is right, but I tried `https.get.on.mockResolvedValue({})`

```js
https
  .get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1', apiRes => {
    console.log('statusCode:', apiRes.statusCode);
    console.log('headers:', apiRes.headers);

    apiRes.on('data', d => {
      process.stdout.write(d);
      res.status(200).json({
        message: 'message'
      });
    });
  })
  .on('error', e => {
    console.error(e);
    res.status(500).json({
      error: 'error'
    });
  });
```

I'm able to mock up to the `https.get()`. But as is if I run a jest test I get `https.get(...).on is not a function`. If I delete the `.on()` piece my test will be able to continue.

Comment: this is code you'd like to test? if yes, why do you want to mock part of it? if no, could you add some description _what you want to do_ (not _in what way_)?

Answer (score 4):

Here is the solution:

`index.ts`:

```js
import https from 'https';

const response = {
  status(code: number) {
    console.log('status code: ', code);
    return response;
  },
  json(data: any) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    return response;
  }
};

function getTodo(res = response) {
  https
    .get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1', apiRes => {
      console.log('statusCode:', apiRes.statusCode);
      console.log('headers:', apiRes.headers);

      apiRes.on('data', d => {
        process.stdout.write(d);
        res.status(200).json({ message: 'message' });
      });
    })
    .on('error', e => {
      console.error(e);
      res.status(500).json({ error: 'error' });
    });
}

export { getTodo };
```

`index.spec.ts`:

```js
import { getTodo } from './';
import https from 'https';
import { EventEmitter } from 'events';

describe('test', () => {
  const emitter = new EventEmitter();
  const httpIncomingMessage = {
    on: jest.fn(),
    statusCode: 'mock status code',
    headers: {
      authorization: 'Bearer mocked token'
    }
  };
  https.get = jest.fn().mockImplementation((uri, callback?) => {
    if (callback) {
      callback(httpIncomingMessage);
    }
    return emitter;
  });
  it('should get todo correctly', () => {
    getTodo();
  });

  it.only('should trigger error event handler correctly', done => {
    getTodo();
    emitter.emit('error', 'error message');
    process.nextTick(() => {
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

Unit test result:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/57283122/index.spec.ts
  test
    ✓ should get todo correctly (10ms)
    ✓ should trigger error event handler correctly (14ms)

  console.log src/stackoverflow/57283122/index.ts:17
    statusCode: mock status code

  console.log src/stackoverflow/57283122/index.ts:18
    headers: { authorization: 'Bearer mocked token' }

  console.log src/stackoverflow/57283122/index.ts:17
    statusCode: mock status code

  console.log src/stackoverflow/57283122/index.ts:18
    headers: { authorization: 'Bearer mocked token' }

  console.error src/stackoverflow/57283122/index.ts:26
    error message

  console.log src/stackoverflow/57283122/index.ts:5
    status code:  500

  console.log src/stackoverflow/57283122/index.ts:9
    {"error":"error"}

  console.error src/stackoverflow/57283122/index.ts:26
    error message

  console.log src/stackoverflow/57283122/index.ts:5
    status code:  500

  console.log src/stackoverflow/57283122/index.ts:9
    {"error":"error"}

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.104s, estimated 3s
```

Comment: `https.get` is a read-only property, how can you assign it?